# PHP- Convert more than one Json string into a single array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a result set which looks something like this:

[image]

For each entry, there can be more than one category and I'm trying to decode these JSON strings and save it in a single array. That means, all these categories will be decoded and saved in an array. This data is fetched from database.

This is the code I tried:

```
//$resultset contains the entire resultset
$resultset_JSON='[["first","second","third","fourth"],["fifth","sixth","seventh","eight","ninth"]‌​,["life","death","business" ,"editing","light"]]';

$data= array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultset))
{
    $data       =   json_decode($row['category']); 
    //$data[]   =   json_decode($row['category']);                      
}
print_r($data);
```

But I'm not getting the desired result. I'm only able to fetch the last row.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

This is the output I'm trying to get:

```
Array 
( 
  [0] => first
  [1] => second
  [2] => third
  [3] => fourth
  [4] => fifth
  [5] => sixth
  [6] => seventh
  [7] => eighth
  [8] => ninth
  [9] => life 
  [10] => death 
  [11] => business 
  [12] => editing 
  [13] => light 
)
```

Comment: Add `[]` at `$data[]=json_decode($row['category']); `

Comment: Tried that. JSON encoded output of the array if i do so is [["first","second","third","fourth"],["fifth","sixth","seventh","eight","ninth"],["life","death","business"
,"editing","light"]] @Saty

Comment: Okk use it as `$data[]       =  $row['category'];` and outside while loop `json_decode($data)`

Comment: Not working...tried it. @Saty

Comment: $data[]=json_decode($row['category'],true);  and use array_merge

Comment: But there is only array and each json string is stored in its locations. Don't we need two arrays to do the merge process?  @jothi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$final_array = array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultset))
{

  $temp_data       =   json_decode($row['category'],true); 
  $final_array     =   array_merge($final_array ,$temp_data);  

 }

 print_r($final_array );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_merge in your loop

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 1):

```
Please try this code:

$data= array();
$ds= array();
$f ='';
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultset)){
{
    $data      =   json_decode($row['category']);   
    $f .= implode(',',$data);                       
}
if(!empty($f)) {
  $ds = explode(',',$f);
}
print_r($ds);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $resultset_JSON='[["first","second","third","fourth"],["fifth","sixth","seventh","eight","ninth"]‌​,["life","death","business" ,"editing","light"]]';

  $all_data = array();
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultset)){
      //Fetch array
      $data       =   json_decode($row['category']); 
      $all_data   =   array_merge($all_data,$data);                      
  }
  var_dump($all_data);
```